# QGIS Raster Attribute Table missing COUNT field

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-attribute-table

I am using QGIS 3.30, I can create a Raster Attribute Table :

[image]

However, the table doesn't have any COUNT field. Any idea what's the problem?

[image]

The Q1 layer is rendered using "unique values".